# JavaScript - Forms - Validating numbers and email

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

I am not great with scripting or coding, so I'm really sorry if this is a silly question.

I have a form:

```
<form name="userinfo" action="validform.html" method="post" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Personal Information</legend><br />

        <label for="firstname">First Name:</label>
        <input type="text" id="firstname" name="firstname">
        <span id="firstname_required"></span><br />

        <label for="surname">Surname:</label>
        <input type="text" id="surname" name="surname">
        <span id="surname_required"></span><br />

        <label for="tel">Tel No:</label>
        <input type="tel" id="tel" name="tel">
        <span id="tel_required"></span><br />

        <label for="email">Email:</label>
        <input type="email" id="email" name="tel">
        <span id="email_required"></span><br />

        <label for="password">Password:</label>
        <input type="password" id="password" name="password">
        <span id="password_required"></span><br />

        <label for="submit"></label>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit!">
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

The form works great.

I would like to validate the Tel No, so that only digits between 0-9 can be entered.  I'm not worried about length or anything rock n roll like that.  I just want to make sure that users enter in numbers, then I can expand on that.  Here is my code:

```
function validateNumber()
{
        var a=document.forms["userinfo"]["tel"].value;
        var patt=new RegExp("[0-9]");

        if (a==null || a=="")
        {
         document.getElementById('tel_required').innerHTML="required";
        }
        else if (patt==null || patt !== RegExp )
        {
             document.getElementById('tel_required').innerHTML="numbers only allowed";
        }
}
```

I suspect I have something fundamentally wrong in my else if statement ((patt==null || patt !== RegExp )) or that it's even constructed correctly, or that it should even be an else if statement!!  But I can't even seem to get the logic quite right in my head.

Any help would be great.  Thanks, and again sorry if this is a silly question.

Here is the full JavaScript code I have so far:

```
function validateForm()
    {
        var a=document.forms["userinfo"]["firstname"].value;

        if (a==null || a=="")
                {
                    document.getElementById('firstname_required').innerHTML="required";
                }


        var a=document.forms["userinfo"]["surname"].value;

        if (a==null || a=="")
            {
                document.getElementById('surname_required').innerHTML="required";
            }

validateNumber()
validateEmail()


        var a=document.forms["userinfo"]["password"].value;

        if (a==null || a=="")
            {
                document.getElementById('password_required').innerHTML="required";
                return false;
            }

    }

function validateNumber()
{
var a=document.forms["userinfo"]["tel"].value;
var patt=new RegExp("[0-9]");

if (a==null || a=="")
            {
                document.getElementById('tel_required').innerHTML="required";
            }

 if (patt==null || patt !== RegExp )
            {
                document.getElementById('tel_required').innerHTML="numbers only allowed";
            }
}


function validateEmail()
{
var a=document.forms["userinfo"]["email"].value;
var patt=new RegExp("/^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/");

if (a==null || a=="")
            {
                document.getElementById('email_required').innerHTML="required";
            }
}
```

Comment: You should note that most people either enter spaces or other non 0-9 characters for telephone numbers, and therefore should not be restricted to 0-9

Comment: Well, I'm assuming you'll call this function every time some action is entered into that input box, so one case you seem to be missing is something to clear the inner html once the input inside the box matches what you're looking for.

Comment: You're not even testing your regex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are lucky enough to be HTML5, you might be able to get away with

```
<input type="number">
```

Try input type=number to see the HTML5 version in action.

else try below code

```
function validateNumber()
{
        var a=document.forms["userinfo"]["tel"].value;

        if (a==null || a=="")
        {
         document.getElementById('tel_required').innerHTML="required";
        }
        else if (/[^\d]/.test(a)) 
        {

             document.getElementById('tel_required').innerHTML="numbers only allowed";
        }
    else {
         document.getElementById('tel_required').innerHTML="input OK";
         }
    }
```

Comment: Actually, I have just had another go with your code and now a message appears saying "numbers only allowed" if I type in  text!!!!  A little bit closer I think!!

Comment: happy coding :) please tick as answer.

Answer (score 0):

As Novocaine88 says, you should also allow spaces.

```
if (!/[^\d ]/.test(a)) {
    //OK
} else {
    //not OK - contains character(s) other than numbers/spaces
}
```

Note the simpler method of declaring a regular expression, also, via the literal `/pattern/` rather than the constructor.